# How to change Label size of QPieSlice in QtChart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtchart

I tried using the slice.setLabelFont(font) but its not working,
I have attached my code below

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #Load the UI Page
        THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'main.ui')
        uic.loadUi(my_file, self)

        # changing the background color to cyan
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #363636;")
  
        # set the title
        self.setWindowTitle("Screen Time")

        # self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        # self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        font=QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(20)
        font.setPointSize(20)
        

        series = QtChart.QPieSeries()
        series.setHoleSize(0.5)
        series.append("Example1 40%",40.0)
        
      
        slice = QtChart.QPieSlice()

        slice.setLabelFont(font)

        slice = series.append("Example1 30%",30.0)
        slice.setLabelVisible()
        
        series.append("Example1 30%",30.0)

        chart = QtChart.QChart()
        
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitleFont(font)
        chart.setTitle('usage time')
        
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QtChart.QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        chart.setTheme(QtChart.QChart.ChartThemeDark)
        #chart.animation

        chart.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("transparent")))
        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chartview = QtChart.QChartView(chart)
        chartview.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.chart_container.setStyleSheet("background-color: #363636;")

        self.chart_container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.chart_container)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(chartview)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. First, you are calling `setLabelFont` on a QPieSlice that never gets added to the QPieSeries.

```
slice = QtChart.QPieSlice() # this is never added to the series
slice.setLabelFont(font)

slice = series.append("Example1 30%",30.0) # creates and returns a new pie slice
slice.setLabelVisible()
```

And second, setting the chart theme to `QChart.ChartThemeDark` will change the font back to the default, so it must be set before the QPieSlice label font. As mentioned in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#ChartTheme-enum):

> Changing the theme will overwrite all customizations previously applied to the series.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #Load the UI Page
        THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'main.ui')
        uic.loadUi(my_file, self)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #363636;")
        self.setWindowTitle("Screen Time")

        chart = QtChart.QChart()
        chart.setTheme(QtChart.QChart.ChartThemeDark)

        font=QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(20)
        font.setPointSize(20)
        
        series = QtChart.QPieSeries()
        series.setHoleSize(0.5)
        series.append("Example1 40%",40.0)
        
        slice = series.append("Example1 30%",30.0)
        slice.setLabelVisible()
        slice.setLabelFont(font)
        
        series.append("Example1 30%",30.0)
        chart.addSeries(series)
        
        chart.setTitleFont(font)
        chart.setTitle('usage time')
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QtChart.QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        chart.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("transparent")))
        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chartview = QtChart.QChartView(chart)
        chartview.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.chart_container.setStyleSheet("background-color: #363636;")

        self.chart_container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.chart_container)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(chartview)
```